# How to show an image from local images folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show a logo in the header of React web app. The code given below works well, but it needs that the logo is uploaded to an external images repository:

```
<img src="https://upload....mylogo.png" alt="logo" className={classes.logo} />
```

Is there any way to show a logo that is located in `/images` folder of the web app project instead of pointing to an external image?

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  logo: {
    width: '20%',
    maxWidth: 100,
    float: 'left',
    position: 'relative',
    margin: '10px 15px 15px 10px'
  },
  author: {
    width: '20%',
    maxWidth: 100,
    float: 'right',
    position: 'relative',
    margin: '10px 15px 15px 10px',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    textDecoration: 'none'
  }
});

export function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <div>
          <img src="https://upload....mylogo.png" alt="logo" className={classes.logo} />
          <h1>My header</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import the logo from the `/images`

```js
import logo from 'images/logo.png'

/*use it*/

<img src={logo} alt="" className="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `../` to go back the upper directory and `./` for the current directory.

If the directory of your image is `src/image/logo.png` and `src/components/Headers` for the react file. Use the following code:

```
<img src={"../image/logo.png"} alt="" className="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can drag the image from your file explorer and drop it in your browser and than copy and paste the url. It should look something like file:///C:/myimages/image.jpg

The problem with this approach is that you can't deploy or share your project because your users will need to have this image in the correct path on their local computer.

If you used create-react-app to create your react app than you can put it in the public folder and then in the image add the following attribute: `<img src="/image.jpg" />`.

This format is called "Relative URL". When you run "npm start", Webpack serves the public folder and when the browser sees "/image.jpg" it will go to the the root of the served folder(public in our case) and search for "image.jpg".